# Dynamicaly updating SEO data for SPA without history API

Tags: vue.js, seo, single-page-application, json-ld

We are developping a SaaS for our customers in the shape of an SPA with VueJS.

We would like our app to appear in the google results on the search of an item. So if you search for the term "item of some brand" in google, our app is returned because you can buy that item on it. Preferably, returning the corresponding item url.

For infrastructure reasons, we cannot rely on the history API for our links in the app. So the google bot cannot crawl our links, which is obviously a bad start...

However, I came to an idea which we would like your expertise/insights on.

Since we are building some kind of webshop, would an **initial** JSON-LD containing an array of references to the products with their respective url work ?
Something like :

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "someType",
  "itemsOrWhatever": [
    {
      "@type": "itemOrWhatever",
      "name": "Some item name",
      "url": "https://my.app.com/#/item/myItemId"
    },
    {
      "@type": "itemOrWhatever",
      "name": "Some item name",
      "url": "https://my.app.com/#/item/myItemId"
    },
    {
      "@type": "itemOrWhatever",
      "name": "Some item name",
      "url": "https://my.app.com/#/item/myItemId"
    }
  ]
}
```

Would it also work if, for each page, we update the SEO tags in the page's head ? Especially the JSON-LD part ?

Answer (score 0):

As Google and other SEs are eventually improving their crawling mechanism for SPAs, you can tackle few ways via Vue without History mode.

1) for dynamic `<head>` issue with routing, you can fixed with `vue-meta` to work with your `title`, `description` and other meta keywords along with your routing

2) via SSR such as NUXT (it's part of Vue and dynamic link friendly)

3) Google Webmaster/ Search Console might be your best friend to tackle/solve problems of SPAs as you could.

Comment: Thanks for Vue-meta lib. However your answer is not related to the actual question. Also, since we did develop a SPA, we won't go back from scratch building a SSR solution...